# Как использовать html элемент в objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Сейчас пишу программу на iOs, хотел бы использовать эту строку, но не знаю как можно использовать ее в objective c. Кто-нибудь, подскажите, пожалуйста, есть совместимость этих двух языков в одном коде и как можно заменить эту строку

```
(`HTML!!!! = " input type="button" value="Просмотр страницы" onclick="viewPage()""
```

в objective c. Заранее спасибо, буду признателен за ответ!

Comment: Я глаз сломал пока читал. :( Скажите проще что нужно?

Comment: Скайп есть?Можно очень просто обьяснить)

Comment: В общем в окне  пишется код на html и при нажатии этой кнопки открывается вкладка где код показан как веб страница.Надо сделать подобную функцию под Objective C.

Comment: Нужно нажать на ссылку в окне аппликации, чтобы она открылась в окне браузера, чтоли?

Comment: Нет,при вводе в окне кода и при нажатии далее этой кнопки,код демонстрируется в сафари как веб документ,тоесть как он будет выглядеть в формате хтмл!

Comment: ох ты ж елки маталки, нельзя было это сразу написать в вопросе?
Короче в одном окне аппликации нужно сделать обычное поле ввода (TextField), под ним кнопку, при нажатии на которую событие передается в контроллер. В контроллере считывается значения текстового поля, генерируется WebView. В это WebView втсавляется содержимое текстового поля и показывается в окне.

Comment: У меня есть несколько вопросов,ты бы не мог бы помочь,желательно в скайпе.А так спасибо)